# Вложенный список из PHP и массивов

Tags: php

Написал такой код:

```
<?php
$a0 = [1,2];
$a1 = [3,4];
$a2 = [5,6];
$a3 = [7,8];
$a4 = [9,10];
$a5 = [11,12];
$a6 = [13,14];

$a = [$a0,$a1,$a2,$a3,$a4,$a5,$a6];
echo $values = array_values($_GET);
foreach($a as $b):
?>
<ul>
<li>
<!--Здесь код-->
</li>
</ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

`$a0` - родительский, из `$a0` идут: `$a1` и `$a2`. Из `$a1` идут: `$a3` и `$a4`. Из `$а2` идут: `$a5` и `$a6` и т.д. бесконечный уровень вложенности.
Пример:
`$a0`
`$a1 $a2`
`$a3 $a4 $a5 $a6`
и т.д.

Как правильно реализовать такое дерево с помощью цикла и суперглобального массива $_GET (к примеру: `site.ru/index.php?group=0`)?

Answer (score 1):

Структура данных которую вы пытаетесь описать называется **графом**.

Т.к. уровень вложенности и высота графа не ограничена, то вам нужен алгоритм обхода графа в ширину. Думаю, вам поможет статья [Структуры данных, PHP. Часть вторая](https://habrahabr.ru/post/190474/).

Если я всё правильно понял, то после реализации обхода в ширину, вам нужно будет просто передать номер или имя стартовой вершины через `$_GET`, чтобы релизовать все ваши идеи.